# how to create array object use jquery

Tags: jquery, highcharts

need help to jquery create array object
this my script

```
        var label = [];
        var datayear = [];
        var datamonthsales = [];
        var datamonthtrans = [];

        url = "list-chart-national-global";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.data) {
                    hideSpinner();
                    var i = 0;
                    $.each(data['data'], function (key, value) {
                        var monthlabel = value["month"];
                        var year = value["year"];
                        var monthsales = value["sales"];
                        var monthtrans = value["transaction"];

                        label.push(monthlabel);               
                        datayear.push(year);
                        datamonthsales.push(monthsales);
                        datamonthtrans.push(monthtrans);
                    });
//                    console.log(dataallmonthsales);
                }
            }
        });

$('#container1').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Sales',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: kfc@ffi.co.id',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: label
    },
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                if (this.value >= 1000000000000) {
                    return this.value / 1000000000000 + 'T';
                } else if (this.value >= 1000000000) {
                    return this.value / 1000000000 + 'B';
                } else if (this.value >= 1000000) {
                    return this.value / 1000000 + 'M';
                } else if (this.value >= 1000) {
                    return this.value / 1000 + 'K';
                }

            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'sales'
        },
        plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ''
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
            name: '2016',
            data: datamonthsales
        }]
});
```

i want this series get dynamic if i got 2 year like 2015 and datamonthsales grouping by year

like this series [{name:'2016', data:[]},{name:'2015', data:[]}] // dynamic
anyone can help me ?

Comment: try like this `datayear.push({name:monthlabel,data:monthsales})`

Comment: i want result get [{name:'2016',data:[800,200,300]}, {name:'2015', data: [300,100,400]}]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.put it in each function.

```
var queryArr=[];

var sales={
"name": year,
"data":monthsales

};
 queryStr = { "sales" : sales };
     queryArr.push(queryStr);
```

Comment: i want get result [{name:'2016',data:[800,200,300]}, {name:'2015', data: [300,100,400]}]